# How to add kaggle dataset download stats in github readme file?

Tags: github, download, kaggle, badge, readme

I am trying to add a badge type indicator in the github readme to show how many dataset downloads from the kaggle have occured so far (much like showing page visit count, etc). Is there any way to add this?
Particularly, I want to display this number of **602** downloads and the counter should update automatically with new downloads in real-time.
[image]

I didnt find any specific badge to integrate in the readme (from shield.io or elsewhere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do it would be to implement your own web scraper and use a github workflow to periodically scrape the required data.

## Crude Python implementation

### Create requirements.txt file

In the root directory of your github repository, create a `requirements.txt` file with the following:

```
selenium==4.6.0
```

The selenium web scraper will be used to fetch data from the kaggle website.

### Create script

In the root directory of your github repository, create a `badge_generator.py` file with the following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


def update_readme(readme_file_path, badge_id, new_badge):
    new_file_content = ''
    # id used to identify position of badge
    line_id = f'![kaggle-badge-{badge_id}]'
    badge_found = False

    # open readme and update badge
    with open(readme_file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        # get all lines in readme
        lines = [line for line in f]
        for i in range(0, len(lines)):
            if line_id in lines[i]:
                # replace old badge with new badge
                lines[i] = new_badge
                badge_found = True
                break
        # concatenate lines
        new_file_content = ''.join(lines) if len(lines) > 0 else new_badge

    if not badge_found:
        raise Exception(
            str(f"Badge {badge_id} not found in {readme_file_path}"))
    # update readme
    with open(readme_file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(new_file_content)


def create_badge(badge_id, badge_value,
                 badge_name='Downloads', badge_color='orange'):
    badge_url = (f'https://img.shields.io/badge/{badge_name}'
                 f'-{badge_value}-{badge_color}')
    markdown = (f'![kaggle-badge-{badge_id}]({badge_url})\n')
    return markdown


def get_download_count(kaggle_url: str):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

    driver.get(kaggle_url)
    time.sleep(3)
    downloads_element = driver.find_element(
        By.XPATH,
        '//*[@id="site-content"]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[6]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/h1')
    download_count = downloads_element.get_attribute("textContent")
    return (download_count)


def main():
    readme_file_path = "README.md"  # relative to root directory
    # change this url
    url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/utkarshx27/marijuana-arrests-in-columbia'
    badge_id = 1  # each badge must be given a unique id
    x = get_download_count(url)
    y = create_badge(badge_id, x)
    update_readme(readme_file_path, badge_id, y)


main()
```

Replace the value of `url` in `main` function with the URL of the kaggle card.

### README modifications

Your `README.md` file must be in root directory. In your README file, add the following line at a line number where you want the badge to be:

```
![kaggle-badge-1]()
```

This line should be present before running script. When script is run, this line will be overwritten and the badge is updated.

**Do not write anything else on this line.**

### Create github workflow

Create a `.github` folder in the root directory of your github repository and inside this folder create another folder `workflows`. Place `badge.yml` inside `workflows`:

```yaml
name: Kaggle Badge Generator

on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 * * * *' #  run every hour

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      - name: checkout repo content
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: setup python with pip cache
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.9' 
          cache: 'pip' # caching pip dependencies

      - name : install any new dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
          
      - name: execute py script 
        run: python badge_generator.py 
        
      - name: commit files
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
          git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
          git add -A
          timestamp=$(date -u)
          git diff-index --quiet HEAD || (git commit -a -m "Last badge update : ${timestamp}" --allow-empty)
          
      - name: push changes
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          branch: main
```

The python script will run every hour and will update the badge. The cron job can be modified to run more frequently.

The badge will look like this:
[image]

Your github file directory structure will be like this:

```
.github/
├─ workflows/
│  ├─ badge.yml
badge_generator.py
requirements.txt
README.md
... your stuffs
```

## Other methods

If you don't want the script to directly modify your README, you will have to implement some sort of API. Look into free [serverless functions on Vercel](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/serverless-functions) or [REST API on Render](https://render.com/docs/api). This could pair with [the dynamic badges Actions](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/dynamic-badges).